# Azure functions to send email with logo using sendgrid

Tags: python, azure-functions, sendgrid

I am sending email from Azure functions using python and sendgrid. I am able to form the other part of the email but when I am trying to insert logo in signature of the email is not displaying that. Rest HTML is rendering fine.(till href)

Following is my code :

```
    import sendgrid
    from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
    from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

    message = Mail(
                        from_email=email_from,
                        to_emails=email_to, 
                        subject=email_subject,

                        html_content= '<br>Hi '+name+ ','+
                        '<br>body of the email. Working fine.' +
                        '<br><a href='+no+'>No'</a>\n' +
                        '<br><br>LOGO--><img src="doc.png" alt="W3Schools.com"/>'+
                        '</html>'
                            )
    response = sg.send(message)
    print(response.status_code)
```

I tried pointing out URL in src too and it did not help.

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are 3 options to achieve this:**

- CID Embedded Images (Inline Images)
- Inline Embedding (Base64 Encoding)
- Linked Images

Check out below links for implementation details:

- https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/
- https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/issues/736